# How to add PHP to Linux Mint 20 (with Apache2 & MySQL already instaled)

Tags: php, apache, linux-mint

Linux newbie here and just installed Linux Mint version 20.
To install Apache, PHP, and MySQl on the system I chose the following instructions I found on the web...

1 - sudo apt install apache2
2 - sudo apt install mysql-server
3 - sudo apt install php7.4 
4 - sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.4
5 - sudo apt install php7.4-mysql 
6 - sudo service apache2 restart

I have already executed the first two lines of the above am ready to do the remaining steps and install php but first... to double check...

My Questions:
a - Are the steps listed above correct?
b - Line two in the above instructions installs mysql-server so why is mysql listed again in line five?
c - What about php7.4-mysqli ?
c1 - Should I remove mysql-server and install mysqli-server?
c2 - Should I install php7.4-mysqli instead of php7.4-mysql?

Thanks for any help. I don't want to mess up on this install.

-- Note: I'll be using Apache, PHP, and MySQL only on the local machine for developing and testing code before it goes live on the net.

-- Note: There are many different and confusing steps on the web so I  chose the above steps.

-- Note: The instructions used php7.0 but I used php7.4 because...
sudo apt search php7
seems to tell me php version php7.4 is the latest in the repository

Comment: this is windows mentality to always have the latest ... I use php5 for example.

Answer (score 2):

> a - Are the steps listed above correct?

they are great

> b - Line two in the above instructions installs mysql-server so why is mysql listed again in
> line five?

in line 5 is not mysql the server, it is a mysql library for php

> c - What about php7.4-mysqli ?

see answer above

> mysql-server and install mysqli-server?

I am not sure but I think there is no such package called mysqli-server, at least in debian we do not have it. mysqli is not a server

you can check it out :

```
apt search <package>
```

> php7.4-mysqli instead of php7.4-mysql?

mysqli is a extension of php but there is no such package.

> c1 - Should I remove...

> c2 - Should I install ...

you can not because there are no such packages ..

Comment: linux mint is a forge of debian

Comment: Max, if you run the following on Linux Mint version 20...<br>
sudo apt search php7 you will see php7.4-mysqli<br>
sudo apt search mysql you will see mysqli-server<br>
So it looks to me like the packages exist.<br>
Wonder if I should install both as my code uses mysqli syntax in it.<br>
FYI, Linux Mint comes in two versions... 1 is based on Ubuntu and the other is based on Debian. Mint is the 2nd most popular distro, 2nd only to Ubuntu... I've read.

Comment: great then compare  `apt show php7.4-mysqli` with `apt show php7.4-mysql` and it will tell you more about the packages

Comment: acording to http://packages.linuxmint.com/search.php?release=Ulyana&section=any&keyword=php7.4-mysqli there is no such package ...php7.4-mysqli, what repository are you using ?

Comment: Whatever came with the Linux Mint version 20 install. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Linux Mint.

COMMANDS

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2
sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl
```

THESE MODULES WERE ALREADY INCLUDED WITH PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2
sudo apt-get install php7.2-common
sudo apt-get install php7.2-cli
sudo apt-get install php7.2-json
```